# How to use jquery fadeToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi everyone i want to learn how to use jquery fadeToggle for my **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/ogEvdB)**

In this demo you can see there is a *click show div* div. When you click this div then `.gelen-mesaj-alani` is showing. My question is how can a hide this div when clicked other area ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.click').on('click',function(){
     $(".gelen-mesaj-alani").fadeToggle(300);
  });                  
});
```

Comment: do you want to hide <div class="click">click show div</div> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the click event on body. if target have no closest element with class `.click` or `.gelen-mesaj-alani` then hide the element:

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
 if($(e.target).closest('.click').length == 0 && $(e.target).closest('.gelen-mesaj-alani').length==0) {
    // click happened outside of menu, hide any visible menu items
   $(".gelen-mesaj-alani").fadeOut(300);
}});
```

**[Working Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYrzMz)**

Comment: This answer really enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: @milind-anatwar so if i have two div what can i do on that time ? Like this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/ogEvdB)

Comment: @innovation: i guess you want something like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyvyJz

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of: [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it)

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```